# How to find a function that can generate set of values

Tags: functions

What are some common techniques for finding functions that can generate set of values that cannot be generated using polynomials? For example let's consider:

$f(1)=3, f(3)=2, f(5)=1, f(7)=0, f(9)=3 ...$

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }x=1\\2&\text{if }x=3\\\vdots\\3&\text{if }x=9\\42&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: If you have $n$ points, there is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ that goes thru those points.

Comment: One topic to look into is "Lagrange interpolation".